# Portability issue in file IO

Tags: c++, g++

The following code doesn't have any effect when I compile and run it in linux (g++). Is it a portability issue? How can I make it work?

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("myfile.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
```

Comment: What is `myfile` and what is the expected effect?

Comment: C++ is all about types. What is the type of `myfile`. What do you mean by `doesn't have any effect`.

Comment: Sorry.. just missed the line. Updated the post. By expected effect, I mean that ouput will be appended in the myfile.txt

Comment: @skeptic: What output? You don't actually do anything with the stream.

Comment: well.. I didn't copy the full code.. I have some codes after that line where I just use "<<" to copy data (myfile << data) ..

Comment: @skeptic: We should not have to pry every detail out of you. Tell us everything about what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what *actually* happens. Post a minimal example that we can all compile and see.

Answer (score 3):

A `std::ofstream` is an *output* stream. By definition, it *cannot* input data. So giving it `fstream::in` as a flag is wrong.

If you want a file stream you can input *and* output to, use `std::fstream`.

Admittedly, this may not be what's causing your problem. But it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason stuff doesn't get written to a file is because you forgot to close the stream when you were done: `myfile.close();` somewhere before the program exits. This flushes the buffer and makes sure everything is actually written to the file, and not sitting in any caches along the way.d